# Databinding datagrid to LocationCollection

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

I have a small issue with a datagrid and a MapPolyLine-LocationCollection.  at the moment i have created a grid with two columns one for longitude and one for latitude.  I have set the ItemsSource of the datagrid to my LocationCollection and have bound the columns to the respective location values such as below

var lonCol = new DataGridTextColumn { Header = "Longitude", Binding = new Binding(Longitude) {Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay}}

this all works fine however, I actually want to have the grid have one single column with the whole coordinate as its displayed value, the reason for this is that i may want to display the item in a different coordinate system (UTM for example), I thought i could do this by somehow using a value converter.  My issue is that I cant see how i make my grid have one column bound to the items in my LocationCollection and display its ToString() value, and secondly how i would then be able to convert the displayed value based on some sort of flag.

Sorry if this is not explained to well.

All help much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible to use only one column in your DataGrid by using a Value Converter

```
// If you don't specify a property path, Silverlight uses the entire object
// For two way binding make sure you bind it to an IList<LocationWrapper>
var theOneColumn = new DataGridTextColumn ( 
    Header = "Long + Lat",
    Binding = new Binding(){ 
        Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,  
        Converter = new LongLatConverter()
    }
);


//Converter
public class LongLatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var loc = value as LocationWrapper;
        return String.Format("Long: {0}, Lat: {0}", loc.Longitude, loc.Latitude);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //...
    }
}

//Wrapper class for Location so two way binding works
public class LocationWrapper
{
    //The actual location object
    public String Location( get; set;}      
    public LocationWrapper(Location loc)
    {
        this.Location = loc;
    }
}
```

For the conversion based on the flag part, you can pass in a Converter parameter to change the behaviour of the converter.

```
var theOneColumn = new DataGridTextColumn ( 
    Header = "Long + Lat",
    Binding = new Binding(){ 
        Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,  
        Converter = new LongLatConverter(),
        ConverterParameter = "UTM" // This is what you want to set
    }
);

// ....
// In the Value Converter
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var loc = value as Location;

    if( (parameter as string).equals("UTM"))
    {
        //return UTM formated long/lat coordinates 
    }
    else
    {
        return String.Format("Long: {0}, Lat: {0}", loc.Longitude, loc.Latitude);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the info, it all looks great however when I create the datagrid with one column in this way as soon as an item is added to the itemssource collection (i.e. the Location Collection) I get an exception informing me that "TwoWay binding requires a Path", any ideas ? :-)

Comment: It seems I overlooked this TwoWay binding problem... You could always create a custom wrapper class for Location that has the Location as a property for this. I'll update my answer to give an example.